# Can not click Rails generated table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

As the title says, clicking any of the table rows in `selection-table` doesn't do anything. The first alert -- `alert("It works on each visit!");` -- does run on every page load. I've tried `.click` and `on('click',function)` to no avail. I can't think of a reason why this wouldn't work other than I made a stupid/simple mistake in traversing the table rows that I can't see.

```js
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    alert("It works on each visit!");
    $('#selection-table tbody tr:not(:first-child)').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert("row clicked");
            var ID = $(this).first().html();
            $('#tokemon_trainer_id').val(ID);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="selection-table" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-border w3-hoverable" >
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <% @list_of_trainers.each do |trainer| %>
      <tr class="selection-row">
        <td><%= trainer.id %></td>
        <td><%= trainer.name %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the turbolinks documentation:

> When possible, avoid using the turbolinks:load event to add event
>   listeners directly to elements on the page body. Instead, consider
>   using event delegation to register event listeners once on document or
>   window.

They make this recommendation because they aren't guaranteeing `turbolinks:load` doesn't occur before the document has finished loading (i.e.  Your rows may not actually exist - so nothing would get attached).  The code below uses event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', '#selection-table tbody tr:not(:first-child)', function () {
    alert("row clicked");
    var ID = $(this).first().html();
    $('#tokemon_trainer_id').val(ID);
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#selection-table tbody tr:not(:first-child)', function () {
    console.log("row clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id='result'></div>
<table id="selection-table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selection-row">
    <td><%= trainer.id %></td>
    <td><%= trainer.name %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still doesn't work. I took a look at event delegation and your code does make sense. Maybe I'm using rails asset pipeline incorrectly? I have the JS file in the `assets/javascripts` folder with what I believe to be the correct includes in the manifest file. I have `gem jquery-rails` installed and I have this line `   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` in `application.html.erb`. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: Never used turborails sorry, can't help with that part of it.  Might be an idea to put it in a jsfiddle.  I've validated the above code is correct (see the snippet).  Might be an `id` issue or table structure issue

Comment: @Extreme112 It's maybe an idea to have a look at the source of the rendered table.  Might give more of a clue.  Or change the click selector to `'.selection-row'` instead of `'#selection-table tbody tr:not(:first-child)'`

Comment: Yeah I'm trying that now. I decided to put the script within the page, and now I'm sure my jQuery is wrong. Thanks again for the suggestions and help.